# office power just surged, why can't I connect to any FTP?

Tags: ftp, mac, electrical-power

Normally I wouldn't bother because the problem will surely be resolved shortly, but I thought someone here might know.

Our office just had a power surge, but now I can't connect to any FTP servers. None of them are located here, and not all of them are even related at all. I just keep getting **connection refused**.

Comment: Are you the IT guy for your office? If not, this isn't the best forum for this question. Unless your IT guy spends his time on this site, and if you just had a power outage, he better be working on it, not here :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's FTP and FTP only (you made it to serverfault, so I guess web browsing works) then my first guess is that your router/firewall has ended up configured to block FTP.  Dead hardware would almost certainly affect everything equally (especially if these ftp sites are unrelated, so they wouldn't be connected through a VPN or some other special network connection).  If it's a fancier one (say, a Cisco PIX instead of a $40 linksys) my first guess is that it was originally configured to block FTP, then later someone came and configured FTP access but forgot to commit the change to flash.  Now the power finally blinked, and the unsaved firewall changes were lost.

The problems with this theory are that firewalls are typically configured to drop connections rather than return a connection refused packet, and that most firewalls would allow outgoing FTP by default (as long as you were using passive mode... which wouldn't be an issue until you actually try to download something from the FTP server.

Comment: This makes sense -- no hardware seems to have been damaged, but you are correct, we were online except for FTP (maybe other protocols that I wasn't aware of).

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance something fried (routers,servers,NIC,etc).

Can you ping the machine? Maybe the server powered off during the surge and the FTP services weren't set to start on boot?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something died (or at the very least shut down) during the power surge. This might be an entire machine, or it could just be a component like the NIC.

Have you checked that all of your machines, routers, modems etc. are still working correctly?

If they are then it could be that the surge affected some piece of equipment further down (up?) the line at the telephone exchange or ISP.